# Typo at /help/searching

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, spelling

At [/help/searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), it says:

> Relative datas in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date...

But "data" is already plural! (Or, maybe, it's uncountable.)

Also, and perhaps more importantly, "datas" is not even the right word and it should be "dates" instead, but why let that get in the way of a good bit of pedantry?

Comment: [PhDComics on the subject](http://phdcomics.com/comics/archive.php?comicid=1816)

Comment: In that context I am certain it should be **dates**.

Comment: Speaking of help center, [is the search  working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=model)? Please confirm.

Comment: @Firelord I noticed this too, so reported it as a bug: [Search in Help Center is not returning results at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263602/search-in-help-center-is-not-returning-results-at-all)