# Search in Help Center is not returning results at all

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

I've searched for a question on this and cannot find anything. I'm sure there must be one, but if so we'll dupe this and create a better signpost to it.

---

Currently the search function in the Help Center is entirely broken. No results are returned regardless of what is searched for.

This seems to be on all sites, certainly the ones I tried.

Examples using "ask" as the search keyword, as this should most certainly return results (links go directly to each site's help center->search with keyword "ask"):

- [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=ask)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=ask)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=ask)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=ask)
- [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=ask)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/help/search?q=ask)

Comment: +1 I was about to report this.

Comment: +1, and I contacted a  Mod already, though didn't receive any response yet. Here is one such question: [Search functionality not working at the Help Center](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13893/search-functionality-not-working-at-the-help-center/13896#comment81828_13896)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an artifact of failing over data centers where the index wasn't properly created in our Denver colo's Elasticsearch cluster. I've manually kicked it for now and added it to our DR list of things that need love. You should see all help center searches working correctly now.

Thanks for the report!